# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code - errSecInternalComponent

Tags: ios, xcode

Today I tried to archive my project and it keeps failing... I can successfully build and run it... the error shows up when I try to archive **only**!

It seems to have an issue with the `BoltsSwift.framework`... I'm using the `Parse SDK` that's why I have it...

Here's the error logs:

```
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/sotiriskaniras/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NUP-gahxesbdjkqixfcoizgsawlmseit/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/NUP/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/NUP.build/Release-iphoneos/NUP.build/Script-583A75869943ED3BF4CF52AC.sh (in target: NUP)
    cd /Users/sotiriskaniras/Development/nup-repo/ios-code-repository/NUP
    /bin/sh -c /Users/sotiriskaniras/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NUP-gahxesbdjkqixfcoizgsawlmseit/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/NUP/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/NUP.build/Release-iphoneos/NUP.build/Script-583A75869943ED3BF4CF52AC.sh

mkdir -p /Users/sotiriskaniras/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NUP-gahxesbdjkqixfcoizgsawlmseit/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/NUP/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/NUP.app/Frameworks
Symlinked...
rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "/Users/sotiriskaniras/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NUP-gahxesbdjkqixfcoizgsawlmseit/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/NUP/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/BoltsSwift.framework" "/Users/sotiriskaniras/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NUP-gahxesbdjkqixfcoizgsawlmseit/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/NUP/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/NUP.app/Frameworks"
building file list ... done
BoltsSwift.framework/
BoltsSwift.framework/BoltsSwift
BoltsSwift.framework/Info.plist

sent 1181983 bytes  received 70 bytes  2364106.00 bytes/sec
total size is 1181590  speedup is 1.00
Code Signing /Users/sotiriskaniras/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NUP-gahxesbdjkqixfcoizgsawlmseit/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/NUP/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/NUP.app/Frameworks/BoltsSwift.framework with Identity iPhone Developer: Themistoklis Drakonakis (69DWD23R7K)
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 4C58E1765EEAB7E38EEFDCD6C7AEA7A9CCFC3484  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/sotiriskaniras/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NUP-gahxesbdjkqixfcoizgsawlmseit/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/NUP/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/NUP.app/Frameworks/BoltsSwift.framework'
/Users/sotiriskaniras/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NUP-gahxesbdjkqixfcoizgsawlmseit/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/NUP/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/NUP.app/Frameworks/BoltsSwift.framework: errSecInternalComponent
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured it out! There was an issue with my Development and Distribution Certificates - not sure what - so I revoked them, created new ones and re-archived! Problem fixed!